# Average of the outside of a truncated normal distribution

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, expected-value, truncated-normal-distribution

I have a sample that is normally distributed ~ $N(\mu,\sigma)$ and truncated between $a,b$ such that $a<b$.

I saw a Wikipedia article that the average of the truncated part is $\mu + \frac{\phi(\alpha)-\phi(\beta)}{Z} \sigma$ where $\alpha = \frac{a-\mu}{\sigma}$, $\beta = \frac{b-\mu}{\sigma}$, and $Z = \Phi(\beta)-\Phi(\alpha)$. Is there a formula that calculates the average of datapoints located outside of the truncated part (i.e., the average of datapoints that are located in the tail on the left and the tail on the right) as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple way is using the total expectation formula:

$$\mu=E[X]=E[X|a<X<b]P(a<X<b)+E[X|X<a\cup X>b](1-P(a<X<b))$$

The expected value, $E[X|a<X<b]$, is given in your post. And, the probability $P(a<X<b)$ can be written in terms of the standard normal CDF quite easily (which is $Z$).

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Done! 

If I understand correctly, the value that I want ($E[X|X<a\cup X>b]$) is $\mu - \frac{(\mu + \frac{\phi(\alpha)-\phi(\beta)}{Z} \sigma)(Z)}{1-Z}$.

Is that correct?

Comment: I think $1-Z$ is the common denominator.